# Who is bigger: Metroplex or Fortress Maximus?

Tags: transformers

In *The Transformers* (G1/80s cartoon continuity), who is bigger: Metroplex or Fortress Maximus?
I've found directly contradictory answers online:

[Google's first hit](https://www.seibertron.com/energonpub/which-was-bigger-fortress-maximus-or-metroplex-t16185.php#:%7E:text=Metroplex%20is%20definitely%20the%20bigger%20of%20the%20two.) says unambiguously that Metroplex is bigger (after seeing this answer, I rationalized its correctness by Metroplex being a city, and Fortress Maximus being, presumably, a fortress).
[This scale chart](https://www.tfw2005.com/boards/threads/new-color-g1-season-1-3-scale-chart.1168174/) shows the opposite: Fortress Maximus is bigger (I don't have anything specific to rationalize this answer's correctness other than that the poster seems to have put a lot of love and effort (and so presumably research) into his post).

Keeping track of all the various continuities' comingling is pretty screwy to me, so I'd prefer an answer that relies solely on the G1 80s TV show or its directly related toy-line as canon
(I'd prefer discounting comic book continuity if possible, and answerers may disregard anything bayverse).

---

Note: when I mentioned using the toyline as reference, I meant using the toyline with respect to their in-universe sizes -- not the physical size of the toys themselves. E.g. maybe pictures on the back of the toys' boxes showed Metroplex and Fortress Maximus next to each other?